# Priority Queue Configuration in Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am running a rails app with unicorn server. I use nginx as the reverse proxy. I have configured a heartbeat api, which provides the heartbeat status to the load balancer.

The problem that I am facing is this - some of the apis have high latency(more than 2 secs), while the loadbalancer client times out in 2 sec. So, in case of high load, the heartbeat api at times takes more than 2 secs to respond and by that time the load balancer client has timed out the request. The load balancer then marks the app as unavailable and stops sending requests.

High latency of the apis is expected.

Is there a way to route the heartbeat api requests to some priority queue and have them served on a priority basis?